# Make SQLAlchemy "or_" operator return only the 1st match

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

guys! I have this one query, written with SQLAlchemy:

```
query = query.filter(
    CollectionCardLink.collection_id == card_id,
    CollectionCardLink.position.in_([0, count-1]),
    or_(CardStyle.user_id == referrer_id, CardStyle.user_id == ANYONE_USER_ID)
).all()
```

My issue is: this => `or_(PostStyle.user_id == current_user_id, PostStyle.user_id == DEFAULT_USER_ID)` returns me two records, cause there are records for current_user_id and for DEFAULT_USER_ID in table too.
But I want `or_` to work like it works in Python: stop checking after 1st True. So, I need to get PostStyle for DEFAULT_USER_ID only if there's no PostStyle for current_user_id.
Can someone help, please, with that issue?

Also I tried to code: `(PostStyle.user_id == current_user_id or PostStyle.user_id == DEFAULT_USER_ID)` but it gives me a record for DEFAULT_USER_ID firstly and that's incorrect

Comment: That is not how it works in python either. This is a filter. You are filtering all rows to get those which match. You can either make two selects, or get what you have now and then choose just one of the results. You _could_ also and use `limit` to get only the first result, but you could not be sure which one would be first.

Comment: As @zvone indicates use limit, but also add the following: `order by case when PostStyle.user_id = current_user_id then 0 else 1 end`. If both exist then `current_user_id`  will always be first. That is the raw SQL unfortunately I do not know how to write it in your  obscurification manager (SQLAlchemy) so you will need to translate.

Comment: @Belayer
can u, pls, show me, how it could be implemented with code? i'm not quite sure i understand where a have to put your extra-instuctions

Comment: Sorry, but as I indicated I do not know your obscurification manager (SQLAlchemy). However, the location would be the same a the `order by` (sort) clause would go. What you are basically doing is replacing  sorting on a column by sorting on the result of an expression.